# Live streaming with ffmpeg is gittery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

I started playing around with live streaming with ffmpeg to my rtmp server and was wondering what's the best approach to it if my approach is sending a chunk of data every 5 or so seconds, because right now it's kind of gittery and stuttery every time the server gets data. 
Would appreciate any advice or books/articles about this topic in general so I could get the basic idea.

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: It depends on network bandwidth and what video quality you need.